# Semi-transparent layer over ListView in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, zooming

In Delphi XE2, I have a ListView with thumbnails of images. When I click one of the thumbnails, I want the ListView to be covered with a dark semi-transparent layer and have the clicked image zoomed on top of this layer.

Since it is not possible to put a TImage on top of a ListView, I tried to use another form with AlphaBlend 128 transparency for the layer. However, this AlphaBlend form makes also the TImage on it Alpha-transparent.

So the target seems be to make the layer form AlphaBlend-transparent but not the image on it. How can this be achieved?

---

EDIT on 7.Aug.2012:

SOLVED!! Thanks to Remy Lebeau, who gave me the decisive hint to parenting the image. I've found TW7Image from TMS which is the only image type I know having an Opacity (i.e. AlphaBlend) property. I used this procedure:

In W7Image, load a Black image in Picture property, set Opacity to 192 and set Stretch mode.

Set other image to Center, Proportional etc, then:

```
// In this order (!):
// 1.
imgSemiTransparentBlackLayer.Parent := MyListView;
imgSemiTransparentBlackLayer.Align := alClient;
// 2.
imgTop.Picture.LoadFromFile('MyPicture.png');
imgTop.Parent := MyListView;
imgTop.Align := alClient;
```

Comment: Applying AlphaBlend will be across the entire form, and I don't think this is what you want. You will need to do some custom drawing, I personally don't have the expertise to give you a solid answer, but I can tell you now there will be some dirty drawing tricks done here. Using another VCL control layered on top won't be the answer, but applying entire custom drawing on this list's canvas is where you would need to go.

Comment: And by "dirty drawing tricks" I mean it will involve a bunch of extra code which doesn't necessarily come with Delphi, there will be some Windows API calls most likely, and Delphi doesn't come with an easy way to do this.

Comment: The problem could be easily solved if I could find a way to restrict AlphaBlend transparency only to a certain part of the form.

Comment: It is technically possible.  The Win32 API `UpdateLayeredWindow()` function can be used to set up per-pixel alpha blending and transparency, but that uses a very different type of painting scheme, and `TForm` normally uses `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` instead.

Comment: You can use a semi transparent PNG or 32bit-BMP (both you can create directly in Delphi, no need to load them from a file) and use it in a TImage. Then you have opacity in TImage too.

Comment: No feedback signs you're satisfied with the result. Then don't forget to accept Remy's answer [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) since he gave you the idea ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `TForm.AlphaBlend` property applies to the entire `TForm` as a whole.  What you need is per-pixel alpha-blending instead, which `TForm` does not natively support.  You could call `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to implement per-pixel alpha, but that may conflict with the VCL's use of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`.

For a purely VCL solution, you could try using two `TForm` objects.  Have one `TForm` contain just the `TImage` and no background, then have a second `TForm` lay on top of it, where the second `TForm` has both its `TransparentColor` and `AlphaBlend` properties enabled, has a square of the `TransparenColorValue` that is the same dimensions as the `TImage`, and has a dark background color that gets alpha-blended with whatever is underneath it.

An alternative solution would be to use the Win32 API `CreateWindowEx()` function directly to create the image window, then you can use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` on it.  That requires you to create an in-memory bitmap to back the window drawing, so you can draw your image directly on to that bitmap, rather than using a `TImage` component.  Then you just give it a dark background and specify a per-pixel alpha for the bitmap pixels surrounding the image pixels.

BTW, you **can** put a `TImage` on top of a `TListView`, if you set the `TListView` as the `TImage.Parent`.  You just won't be able to alpha-blend the `TImage`, that's all.